# R: Is it possible to use RGL in x64 Windows?

Tags: windows, r, 64-bit, windows-7-x64, rgl

Is it possible to use the R package 'RGL' in x64 Windows?

[RGL Website](http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=234)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely is. R 2.11.0 just came out and includes support for 64-bit builds on Windows. There is at least one hard-to-install packages that are otherwise supported on 32-bit AFAIK, but rgl installs simply with install.packages.

The R for Windows download page on CRAN includes a link to the 64-bit build, in 2.12.0 this is planned to be integrated with a single installer.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, why not?  It is the same as for other platforms:

- GL hardware support from your card and drivers is required
- proper libraries have to be available

You just pointed to the code archive at R-Forge which does not yet do win64 builds.  It may be better to

- check Brian Ripley's site and / or
- check with the package maintainers

and that last step is generally the recommended method anyway.